# Why is my page displaying differently when running my site as opposed to on jsfiddle?

Tags: asp.net, html, razor, jsfiddle

My html:

```
<section class="featured">
<div class="content-wrapper">
 <h1>Hey! This is private!!!</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>(Not really) Opt In or Out</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectTwitter" name="selectTwitter">I'm Twitterpated!</input>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectBingSearch" name="selectBingSearch">Bing Search</input>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectDuckDuckGoSearch" name="selectDuckDuckGoSearch">Duck Duck Go Search</input>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectYouTube" name="selectYouTube">You Tuber!</input>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectFlickr" name="selectFlickr">Flickr</input>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectWikipedia" name="selectWikipedia">Wikipedia</input>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAmazon" name="selectAmazon">amazon</input>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectFlickr" name="selectFlickr">Fakebook</input>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubit" name="btnSubmit" value="Save Config changes</input><br />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

...displays as I would expect on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/CTyVk/)

But when I run my site, it appears like so:

[image: form and fieldset behaving badly]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close `<input>`.. in `<input type="submit" id="btnSubit" name="btnSubmit" value="Save Config changes</input><br />`

Comment: Righto; awed/odd that jsfiddle doesn't give a darn about that.

Comment: @ClayShannon : Check: view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/CTyVk/show/
They do not include incomplete tags..

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `">` in your submit button code. Try:

```
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubit" name="btnSubmit" value="Save Config changes"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks to you, too - it is still odd that in the bad rendering, a "footer class=" appears in the html markup displayed. I reckon this is from _SiteLayout.cshtml, but why would it be truncated like that? Just kind of wondering to myself, not a "real" question...

Comment: Since the value attribute of the input tag for the submit button was never closed with a double quote `"`, the browser is trying to stick the rest of your code in there as the value. `<footer class="` is the first place it encountered another double quote `"` to close off the value attribute of the submit button.